# Enable and access OS X remote desktop through SSH?

Tags: macos, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc

I'm on vacation and need to run a GUI program on my Mac at home. I can get to a console through SSH, but otherwise the machine is behind a firewall. How can I...

1. Enable VNC from the command line
2. Tunnel that through SSH to my MacBook

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

On your Mac at home:

If you have set the VNC password on your home Mac ... copy the contents of the file below:

```
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.VNCSettings.txt
```

If you haven't set VNC password at home, go to

```
System Prefs->Sharing->Computer Settings
```

and set password then copy the string from the file as above.

On remote machine:

```
sudo emacs /Library/Preferences/com.apple.VNCSettings.txt
```

Copy and paste the contents of com.apple.VNCSettings.txt from the home Mac to that .txt file on the remote Mac

Then try sending this command over ssh to the remote Mac:

```
   sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -configure -clientops -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy yes
```

A VNC connection should work now between home and the remote site.

Comment: Assuming it works: nice! As the SSH security may be good enough, I guess *any* password for plain VNC will do. So, to use "welcome", use this as the contents of that file: `60513D0DE4C5A0E2FF1C39567390ADCA`. (That is: this works for my Snow Leopard Mac. No newline in that file.)

Comment: And if you have an Apple Screen Sharing client, then no need to allow for plain VNC access. See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2790 for the command then.

Comment: Since edits must be at least 6 chars, I'm putting this here: In the last command there is a typo. `-clientops` should be `-clientopts`

Comment: How are you supposed to set the VNC password via System Prefs if you don't have desktop access to the remote machine?